# Can't query VIEW in BigQuery with dbplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, google-bigquery, dbplyr, bigrquery

In the following reprex, I create a BigQuery dataset, create a table with `mtcars`, create a view, and then try to query the view.

I can query the table, but the view returns no data.

```r
library(DBI)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(bigrquery)


dataset = bq_dataset(bq_test_project(), "test_dataset")

if (bq_dataset_exists(dataset))
{
  bq_dataset_delete(dataset, delete_contents = T)
}
#> Using an auto-discovered, cached token.
#> To suppress this message, modify your code or options to clearly consent to the use of a cached token.
#> See gargle's "Non-interactive auth" vignette for more details:
#> https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/non-interactive-auth.html
#> The bigrquery package is using a cached token for ariel.balter@gmail.com.

bq_dataset_create(dataset)
#> <bq_dataset> elite-magpie-257717.test_dataset

conn = DBI::dbConnect(
  bigrquery::bigquery(),
  project = bq_test_project(),
  dataset = "test_dataset",
  KeyFilePath = "google_service_key.json",
  OAuthMechanism = 0
)

mtcars %>% head(5)
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2

if (dbExistsTable(conn, "mtcars"))
{
  dbRemoveTable(conn, "mtcars")
}

if (dbExistsTable(conn, "mtcars_view"))
{
  dbRemoveTable(conn, "mtcars_view")
}

dbWriteTable(conn, "mtcars", mtcars) 

dbListTables(conn)
#> [1] "mtcars"
dbExecute(conn,'CREATE VIEW mtcars_view AS SELECT mpg, cyl, disp FROM mtcars')
#> [1] 0
dbListTables(conn)
#> [1] "mtcars"      "mtcars_view"

mtcars_table = tbl(conn, "mtcars")
mtcars_table %>% head(5) %>% collect()
#> Warning: `...` is not empty.
#> 
#> We detected these problematic arguments:
#> * `needs_dots`
#> 
#> These dots only exist to allow future extensions and should be empty.
#> Did you misspecify an argument?
#> # A tibble: 5 x 11
#>    carb    am    vs  qsec    wt  drat   cyl  disp    hp  gear   mpg
#>   <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <int> <int> <dbl>
#> 1     2     0     1  20    3.19  3.69     4  147.    62     4  24.4
#> 2     2     0     1  22.9  3.15  3.92     4  141.    95     4  22.8
#> 3     1     0     1  20.0  2.46  3.7      4  120.    97     3  21.5
#> 4     1     0     1  19.4  3.22  3.08     6  258    110     3  21.4
#> 5     1     0     1  20.2  3.46  2.76     6  225    105     3  18.1
mtcars_view = tbl(conn, "mtcars_view")
mtcars_view %>% head(5) %>% collect()
#> Warning: `...` is not empty.
#> 
#> We detected these problematic arguments:
#> * `needs_dots`
#> 
#> These dots only exist to allow future extensions and should be empty.
#> Did you misspecify an argument?
#> # A tibble: 0 x 3
#> # ... with 3 variables: mpg <dbl>, cyl <int>, disp <dbl>
mtcars_view %>% head(5) %>% select(everything()) %>% collect()
#> Error: Job 'elite-magpie-257717.job_-275OmiomBA46Ukx5QdteyLlR0TN.US' failed
#> x Table name "mtcars" cannot be resolved: dataset name is missing. [invalid]

dbExecute(conn, "DROP TABLE mtcars")
#> [1] 0
dbExecute(conn, "DROP VIEW mtcars_view")
#> [1] 0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The error message said:

```
#> Error: Job 'elite-magpie-257717.job_-275OmiomBA46Ukx5QdteyLlR0TN.US' failed
#> x Table name "mtcars" cannot be resolved: dataset name is missing. [invalid]
```

I'm not sure why such view could be created in the first place, but the SQL for creating the view should be:

```sql
CREATE VIEW mtcars_view AS SELECT mpg, cyl, disp FROM test_dataset.mtcars
```

Comment: That does work. Can you tell me why you need to specify the dataset when creating a view? I don't see that in any examples of sql syntax for creating a view.

Comment: I guess you probably set a default dataset on your request, which is why your table is not quoted with dataset. The reasoning behind this is, the next time you or others queries this view, the default dataset might not be the same, which may cause problem. As to examples, please check this link : https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_view_statement

Comment: However, I do specify the dataset in the connection. Furthermore, if I don't specify the dataset when I create the view, but do specify it when I connect to the table (`mtcars_view = tbl(conn, 'test_dataset.mtcars_view")`) I still get the error. Is this maybe a quirk of BigQuery?